# .NET Core compression/decompression of DMG (Apple disk image) files

Tags: .net-core, compression, .net-standard

Anyone aware of a .NET Core (or .NET Standard) compression library that can handle DMG files? The library should be all managed and should not depend on a specific platform.

Comment: You'll probably need to roll your own. See [this analysis](http://newosxbook.com/DMG.html) for what you'll be up against.